# Vector subscript out of range error?

Tags: c++

I am new at programming at c++, and when I run this, it compiles successfully and outputs the elements of the array but I get an error that says "vector subscript out of range". What is wrong with this code? I looked at some other questions and it did not seem like any of the others had similar examples of vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
    int arraysize;
cout << "Enter the size of your array:" << endl;
cin >> arraysize;
vector<int> numbers(arraysize);
vector<int>::size_type sizecheck = numbers.size();

cout << "This is the unsorted array:" << endl;
for (int z = 0; numbers[z] < sizecheck; z++)
{
    numbers[z] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    cout << numbers[z] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `for (int z = 0; numbers[z] < sizecheck; z++)` with `for (int z = 0; z < sizecheck; z++)` see what happens.

Comment: The problem with your code is that: [you used a] vector subscript [that is] out of range

Comment: It means that the index you provided to the vector `[z]` is too big.

Comment: What do you think `numbers[z] < sizecheck;` does ? And what if you use `z < sizecheck;` instead ?

Comment: Keep in mind that `numbers[z]` doesn't provide any bounds checking. So your code exhibits undefined behavior. You're lucky that whatever IDE you were using caught it.

Comment: @remyabel Microsoft Visual Studio. Best debugger I've ever used.

Comment: @remyabel, The IDE didn't catch it.  The runtime library did.  vector operator[] checks the index in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually would be an infinite loop given infinite memory, however, since there is a finite amount of memory allocated for your vector, it exhibits undefined behavior. `numbers` will value initialize (set each element to `0`), meaning that the condition is always going to be `0 < sizecheck`. Once `z` reaches the amount of elements in your vector, you exceed the array bounds and wander into undefined behavior land.

Your IDE or whatever you're using already caught the error, but you can use the safer variant, `at()` instead of `operator[]`. This will throw an exception and provide useful information. For example:

```
for (int z = 0; numbers.at(z) < sizecheck; z++)
{
    numbers.at(z) = rand() % 10 + 1;
    cout << z << " " << numbers.at(z) << endl;
}

0 2
1 8
2 10
3 9
4 8
5 2
6 3
7 4
8 4
9 2

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 10) >= this->size() (which is 10)
```

As stated in the comments, what you probably meant to do was `z < sizecheck`, although you should make `z` of type `std::vector<int>::size_type` just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

@remyabel has given you the absolutely correct answer, but in addition to that you should consider using an `iterator`rather than an indexed for loop when looping over standard components like `vector`.

e.g.

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
for(it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
{
    *it = rand() % 10 + 1;
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Note: this is only suitable if you are changing the number of elements in the vector as you iterate, as is happening in this case. If you add or remove elements during the iteration you may invalidate your iterator.